# convert mySQL to mySQLi - using a class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

The previous programmer had used a class called database that has the connection string and a bunch of functions. I now have to convert this to MySQLi and I am at a loss.

```
    class database {
        var $sql='';
        var $result='';
        function database( $host='localhost', $user, $pass, $db) {
            // perform a number of fatality checks, then die gracefully
            if (!function_exists( 'mysql_connect' )) {
                //or die( 'FATAL ERROR: MySQL support not available.  Please check your configuration.' );
                exit();
            }

bla..bla..bla - bunch of code goes here

function get_events_by_user($username) {
    $sql = "SELECT event_id FROM user_events WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return $result;
}
}
```

I tried

```
var $link=mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass);
```

to use as

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

but I can not use expression as a variable value and I don't know what else to do.

Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and remember to pass the connection as an argument to your method. Otherwise, you'll get an out of scope issue.

Comment: how do I pass the connection as an argument to my method?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this. 
I think it solves your problem.

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass, $databaseName);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just  bring the $link in every query.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass, $db);

function get_events_by_user($username) {
    $sql = "SELECT event_id FROM user_events WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    return $result;
```

}